# 3D reconstruction with opencv and point cloud library

Tags: opencv

I am working on a project which involve 3d reconstruction and rendering of the 3D scene , I have done up to disparity image and generated the 3D coordinates using opencv 2.1 and after that I am trying to render the 3D scene using point cloud library here I am gtting a crash in the code . I am using windows 7 32 bit.

I am not getting why this error is comming , please help me.

Here is my code

```
      ......


      Mat imgDisparity16S ;    
IplImage stub, *dst_img;

 Mat imgDisparity8U ;

int ndisparities = 16*5;
int SADWindowSize = 5; 

StereoBM sbm(StereoBM::BASIC_PRESET,ndisparities,SADWindowSize);

sbm( object, image, imgDisparity16S, CV_16S ); 

double minVal; 
double maxVal; 

minMaxLoc( imgDisparity16S, &minVal, &maxVal );

printf("Min disp: %f Max value: %f \n", minVal, maxVal); 

imgDisparity16S.convertTo( imgDisparity8U, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));




IplImage ipl_from_mat((IplImage)imgDisparity8U); 
cvNamedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  
cvShowImage("window", &ipl_from_mat);  

cvSaveImage("disparity.jpg",&ipl_from_mat);
cvWaitKey(0);

Mat xyz ;
cout<<"Here"<<endl;
cv::Mat img_disparity = cv::imread("disparity.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

double q[] =
     {

    1, 0, 0, -2.9615028381347656e+02,
    0, 1, 0, -2.3373317337036133e+02,
    0, 0, 0, 5.6446880931501073e+02,
    0, 0, -1.1340974198400260e-01, 4.1658568844268817e+00,

     };
    cv::Mat Q = Mat(4, 4, CV_64F, q);


cv::Mat recons3D(img_disparity.size(), CV_32FC3);

    cv::reprojectImageTo3D(imgDisparity8U,recons3D,Q,true);
cout<<"Here1"<<endl;
cout<<"Here2"<<endl;

saveXYZ("clouds.txt", recons3D);




 std::cout<<"Creating point cloud"<<std::endl;

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr (new                 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

double px, py, pz;
uchar pr, pg, pb;
double Q03, Q13, Q23, Q32, Q33;

uint32_t rgb1;

#ifdef CUSTOM_REPROJECT
    Q03 = Q.at<double>(0,3);
    Q13 = Q.at<double>(1,3);
    Q23 = Q.at<double>(2,3);
    Q32 = Q.at<double>(3,2);
    Q33 = Q.at<double>(3,3);
#endif  
cout<<"Before"<<endl;

cv::Mat img_rgb = Mat(imgDisparity8U.size(),CV_32FC3);

CvMat* img_rgb1 = cvLoadImageM("frame1_0.jpg",1);

cout<<object_filename<<endl;
img_rgb = img_rgb1;
for(int i=0;i<img_rgb.rows ;i++)
    {

    uchar* rgb_ptr = img_rgb.ptr<uchar>(i);





    uchar* disp_ptr = imgDisparity8U.ptr<uchar>(i);
    double* recons_ptr = recons3D.ptr<double>(i);

    for(int j = 0; j < img_rgb.cols; j++)
    {
        uchar d = disp_ptr[j];
        if ( d == 0 ) continue; 
        double pw = -1.0 * static_cast<double>(d) * Q32 + Q33; 
        px = static_cast<double>(j) + Q03;
        py = static_cast<double>(i) + Q13;
        pz = Q23;

        px = px/pw;
        py = py/pw;
        pz = pz/pw;
        px = recons_ptr[3*j];
        py = recons_ptr[3*j+1];
        pz = recons_ptr[3*j+2];

        pb = rgb_ptr[3*j];
        pg = rgb_ptr[3*j+1];
        pr = rgb_ptr[3*j+2];

        pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
        point.x = px;
        point.y = py;
        point.z = pz;



        rgb1 = (static_cast<uint32_t>(pr) << 16 || static_cast<uint32_t>(pg) << 8 || static_cast<uint32_t>(pb));
         point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb1);
        point_cloud_ptr->points.push_back(point);

    }

}


point_cloud_ptr->width = (int)point_cloud_ptr->points.size();
point_cloud_ptr->height = 1;
cout<<"outside loop"<<endl;
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
cout<<"outside loop11"<<endl;

viewer = createVisualizer(point_cloud_ptr); //Error Here

while(!viewer->wasStopped())
{
    viewer->spinOnce(100);
    boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));
}

return 0;
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a little more code than that before anyone can help...

Comment: sorry Now i have added the code , please help me

Comment: umm... that's now a lot of code. Can you try to trim it down to the smallest possible example which still demonstrates your problem? For example, you have a lot of commented out lines - if they're not relevant then delete them.

Comment: You should also post the error message related to your crash. Also, OpenCV 2.1 is quite old right now, if there is any way you can update to the latest 2.4.1, I recommend you to do it. Your crash might even be a long ago corrected bug. The downside is that your code might need changes to be compatible with the recent versions.

Comment: Might be a long shot but I would test if none of point_cloud_ptr elements are null :d

Comment: The crash is not in opencv library it is in PCL(point cloud librery)function.